# angular hybrid app routing is not working, router outlet is always considered root

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, hybrid

I am trying to migrate to angular 2, currently I am trying to make my app hybrid to be able to use both angular 1 and 2 , currently I am struggling with routing, I managed to get bother router in angular 1 and 2 working by  bootstraping angular 2 with the root of angular2 inside it " according to google doc's"

```
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, ['myAPP'], {strictDi: false});

 });
```

so basically I am trying to start migrating from the leaf, so I tried to replace the ui-view with router-outlet , I try to put the router outlet inside states inside the app, states are inner views access in child state in route, I get an exception that the primary outlet is not found .

```
error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'MyNG2Component'
enter code here
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What does your index.html and the root component look like?